# Interview Question with Arrays and Consecutive Subintervals

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I recently came across this question and honestly am pretty unsure of how to solve it, or even begin to develop an algorithm to properly solve it..

The question is:

> "An array of $n$ integers is correctly positioned with respect to an
>   integer $k$ if for any $k$ consecutive indices in the array, there
>   does not exist values at two indices, $x$ and $y$ such that $x \geq 2$
>   * $y$ (where $x$ and $y$ are values at 2 indices of the array in a subarray of size $k$). What is an $O(n \log k)$ algorithm to determine
>   if an array is correctly positioned?"

For example: $[5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 9]$ is not correctly positioned if $k = 4$ since in in the interval $[7, 4, 5, 9]$ we have that $9 \geq 4 * 2$.

My thought is to check all potential subintervals like $[0..k]$, $[1..k+1]$, $[2,..k+2]$ using a min-heap but I really can't think that would satisfy the time constraint since it's resulting in building far too many heaps.

Does anyone know how to approach this problem, or have a solution for it?

Having trouble figuring out how to keep track of this sliding window using heaps, and thinking maybe I have to use a min-heap and max-heap? And compare the max to the min for every subinterval using insertions and deletions?

Comment: You do not need to re-build the heap each time. Just perform insertions and deletions accordingly. Declare an index$\ i$ such that it refers to the start of a sliding window. The first element of the subinterval has index$\ i$ and the last one has index $ i + k - 1$.  this should lead to a$ \ nlogk$ algorithm as required.

Comment: @HendrikJan how would I keep an additional index for each of the elements? Would each integer in the array be an object that has a value, and an index associated with it? In that case, how would the algorithm correctly find the element with the associated index? I just don't understand how we can "easily delete the first number from the heap w/o having to search for it". Are you suggesting starting from the end of the array instead of the beginning? Also, I edited the question since the array in my example has violations of the condition all over the place.

Comment: @JhonRayo99 Right, but should I have a min-heap and a max-heap to properly compare the min and max for every subinterval? If I only keep a pointer index $i$ then I also have to know when I extract the min, what index that is as well, right? If the min is extracted and it's the last element in the subinterval sliding window, then I have to find a new min on the next insertion. Could you please elaborate on how I would perform insertions and deletions accordingly?

Comment: You can delete any element from a heap in$\ O(logn)$ time if you know where it is in the heap. So just keep a reference to the first element in the subinterval.

Comment: If I do that though, I wouldn't just need a reference to the first element in the subinterval I'd also need references to other elements in the subinterval, right? For example with the array: $[5,6,7,4,5,9]$ 

If I create a min-heap of size 4 with $[5, 6, 7, 4]$ and extract the min which is $4$, I'd need to keep $4$ to compare it to the next subinterval $[6, 7, 4, 5]$ and add the next $5$ to the heap, so the heap again will be $[5, 6, 7, 5]$ but I'll need to compare the max from this subinterval to $4$ which was already extracted.. Do you see where my confusion is stemming from?

Comment: I feel like we'd need more than 1 heap at least, and references to the index of the first minimum we extract to see how far we carry that along in the sliding window? I don't know though, I don't see a clear path here and may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: That would be very much appreciated. If I'm understanding correctly, you both are suggesting to not extract the min, and simply compare every element to the root (min) node prior to insertion, to see if meets the condition. 

Once we reach $k$ elements in the heap, we delete the element at the first index of the sub interval (index $0$). From there, we add the next node, and delete the element at the second index, (index $1$) while ensuring we compare each insertion to the current min, and by removing nodes by the order they were added in, we update the min for the subinterval?

Comment: The thing is, I can see keeping track of that index, say we initialize $i$ at 0. And we don't update it until our added element to heap is of index $k - 1$. Then, we remove that element that was at index $0$, and update the index to $1$. Then we add the element at index $k$ (compare to root node), and remove the element at index $1$, to make space to add the next element at index $k + 2$, and update the index now to $2$... Is that the idea essentially? I don't know how we'd properly locate the node in the heap corresponding to a specific index like that though without the node storing info...

Comment: Hint, there is a solution of $O(n)$ time-complexity.

Comment: Well, if you have a subinterval$[i, i + k - 1]$, you can decide if it meets the condition by only considering the smallest element$\ a$ and the largest element$\ b$. If$ \ a * 2 \geq \ b$, then the array is not correctly positioned. The problem reduces to doing this check for every possible sliding window. You need a min-heap and a max-heap. Insertions can be carried out as usual. Deletions, however, need to be done differently. Take a look at indexed priority queues.

Comment: @JohnL. could you please elaborate on this? I don't see how we could possibly come up with a linear time solution for this without considering the potential subintervals.

Comment: @JhonRayo99 right, so a max heap would contain the interval: $[i, i + k - 1]$ and a min heap would contain $[i, i + k -1]$. We could compare the min of the interval to the max of the interval by peeking (or extracting..?) and if the condition isn't satisfied then we exit. However if the condition is satisfied, I'm struggling to see if we extract the min and max, or if we extract the element at index $i$ to fill the next incoming element from the array. I've tried to iterate over at least 10 examples for a few hours, but getting nowhere...

Comment: If the condition is met, you just move to the next sliding window, which involves removing the ith element in the array from the heaps. Otherwise, the algorithm can terminate.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get how we ensure we keep track of the $i^{th}$ element in the array from the heaps. Are we using more than one pointer here to keep track of both the index we're on in the array, and the index of the beginning of the sliding window...? Sorry if I'm missing what you're saying, I just cannot seem to visualize such a solution.

Comment: So I figured out how we'd keep track of the $i^{th}$ element. But, doesn't it take $O(n)$ time to search through a heap and find an element if we don't know the index it's located it within the heap? Unless we maintained a pointer to the index of the 1st element of any subinterval, such that we know what index that 1st element of the subinterval was located in the heap?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea. The accepted answer follows the same procedure, except it uses a different data structure to keep track of the min and the max in constant amortized time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite common belief, maintaining the maximum (or minimum) element out of the last $k$ elements does not involve a $O(\log k)$ factor, and can be done in amortized $O(1)$. Using this twice (once for max and once for min) you can solve your problem in $O(n)$.

The trick is done using a monotonic double-ended queue, one where all the elements are either in descending or ascending order. Furthermore, for each element we keep track of the index we encountered it, so we can invalidate it from the queue.

Suppose that we iterate over elements in a stream, and wish to maintain the *minimum* value (the maximum is analogous). Let's call the current value $x$ and the current index $i$. We first initialize an empty double-ended queue $Q$ and start iterating:

1. Remove all elements from the queue that would be made irrelevant by $x$. Since we know our queue is in ascending order, this is very simple, we keep
   removing elements from the back that are bigger than $x$. They are now irrelevant for the window, as $x$ is newer and smaller.

   ```
   while not empty(Q) and peek_back(Q).value > x:
       pop_back(Q)
   ```
2. Add $x$ to the back of the queue, but keep track of its index as well.

   ```
   push_back(Q, value=x, index=i)
   ```
3. Invalidate old items in the queue. We only have to do this if the item is in the front of the queue, otherwise its harmless (this lazy removal is what allows us to keep $O(1)$ time).

   ```
   while peek_front(Q).index <= i - window_size:
       pop_front(Q)
   ```
4. Now `peek_front(Q)` contains the smallest element in our window, so we can use it and then keep iterating.

Note that steps #2 and #4 are $O(1)$ time, and steps #1 and #3 are $O(r)$ time where $r$ is the number of removed elements from the queue. However since each element is only added once to the queue, the $O(r)$ steps must be amortized $O(1)$.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I am not too familiar with double-ended queues (have limited experience implementing them). Is this still possible to do with a heap (or multiple) using similar logic?

Comment: @fibonnaci_0_1_1 A heap is vastly more complicated than a double-ended queue. A double-ended queue is just a linear data structure that you can quickly append to/remove from on either side (as apposed to a regular dynamic array, where only appends/removals at the end are fast). You can also implement them using linked lists or ring buffers.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I'm familiar with queues and you're definitely right that a double-ended queue is less complex than this. That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Nice!  This is a beautiful solution!

Comment: I think I will use this in my lecture notes as an example of the application of a double ended queue.